# Spring 4 config problems afer migration from v3 (util:properties location is no longer evaluating spEL)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I had a working spring 3 application which after migration to 4.1.0.RELEASE started to cause problems. Configuration below stopped working:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dit_properties_path" jndi-name="dit_properties_path" resource-ref="true" />
<util:properties id="systemProperties" location="classpath:system.properties" />
<util:properties id="serverProperties" location="#{dit_properties_path}"/>
```

After migration it seems that spring is not able to resolve spEL `#{dit_properties_path}`, and is showing following error:

```
[PropertiesFactoryBean] [INFO]:    Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/#{dit_properties_path}]
[...]is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{dit_properties_path}]
```

Jndi resource is of type `java.lang.String` and points to local FS (C:\someFile.properties).
Here's tomcat definition of the resource /server and context/:

```
    <Environment name="dit_properties_path" value="file:C:\someFile.properties"
     type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
```

and

```
<ResourceLink name="dit_properties_path" 
    type="java.lang.String" 
    global="dit_properties_path" />
```

Do anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?
I have several property files in my app which are often accessed by `#{propertyFileId['key']}` and they have to be loaded dynamically from jndi resource path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from :

```
<util:properties id="serverProperties" location="#{dit_properties_path}"/>
```

to:

```
<util:properties id="serverProperties" location="${dit_properties_path}"/>
```

solved the problem. Still, can't figure out why given expression doesn't work with hash sign.